# How to use two USB printers at once in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, printing, windows-xp-embedded, label-printer

I hooked up two USB printers to an XP-embedded system. (a Zebra label printer and regular HP page printer)  Either will work when only one is plugged in.  If both are plugged in, only the HP will print, however documents are queued for the other.  Hooking up a second printer a different way (network) allows both to be used.

What might prevent the second printer from printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP is a bit of a pain for how it sets up printers. It might be worth removing the hp drivers and just using generic PCL5 drivers instead.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK usb printers create a virtual printer port and it's possible that your printers try to use the same virtual port and thus colliding.

You can check which port they use by going into properties for the printer and the ports tab. Connect your printers one by one using usb and check which port they are using.

If they're using the same port maybe you can reconfigure one of them.

Comment: Good idea, but I Checked that already, they are USB001 and USB002, different.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers, most likely. This appears, from what you have said, to be an issue specific to these two pieces of hardware, and thus is not likely to be resolved unless HP or Zebra updates their drivers for XP embedded.